# Get DataRow from the DropDownList

Tags: asp.net

**I doesn't know how to convert the `dropdownlist` selected item to `datarow`**

```
sDropDownList.DataSource = GetTable();  


sDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";    

sDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
```

I tried to get the datarow from the dropdownlist like this.. .

```
   DataRow row = (sDropDownList.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row;
```

But i get an error .. . errors like **Can't convert listitems to datarows**

Comment: Why would you try to convert the selected value from a DropDownList to a DataRow? Doesn't really make sense... What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a `DataRow` on postback. A `DropDownList`'s item has a `Text` and a `Value` since it's a [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx). If you need the other informations from the record later (on postback) you have to query the database again.

Actually you have all you need since you've set the `DataValueField` to the ID-column.

```
int id = int.Parse(sDropDownList.SelectedValue);
// now query the database to get the whole record or the information you need
```